# Please help my input type text in html5 not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, dreamweaver

[image: image here]

I have a problem. Since I'm new to bootstrapping I was customizing this template on startbootstrap.com. But, when I applied input type=text and refreshed my page there's no character to be seen on the actual textbox. It recognizes character but it's invisible.

Here's the code of my login div

```
<!-- Login Section -->
<section id="login" class="content-section text-center">
    <div class="login-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <h2>Log-in</h2>
                <form>
                  <label for="username">Username:</label>
                  <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I think the problem here is not the HTML code. I wouldn't know, I only knew HTML CSS and PHP language in terms of web development. jQuery, bootstrap, and JavaScript are not familiar to me. Please help me.

The CSS code of that particular class:

```
.login-section {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(../img/downloads-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I think you want to be looking at the CSS for the input, rather than `.login-section`. Specifically the text color

Comment: There's no input in my CSS so that wouldn't affect the input type=text. hmmmm..

Comment: @Roch So you can't type in the input field? Or you can type in the input field but the text isn't showing up?

Comment: i can type but text isnt showing up. if i highlighted all the characters copy/cut and pasted it to notepad the text i typed on the textbox will now be visible on the notepad.

Comment: actually i havent seen any insertion point neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.login-section` has the `color` applied as white so your `input` text isn't visible. See example.

```css
section .login-section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  color: #fff;
  background: url(http://www.virtualoceania.net/newzealand/photos/mountains/mtcook/nz0275.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
section #myForm input {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="login" class="content-section text-center">
  <div class="login-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
        <h2>Log-in</h2>

        <form id="myForm">
          <label for="username">Username:</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Its the same code fragment with me but the text inside your textbox is visible.

Comment: There's additional CSS that I added. Otherwise it wouldn't be visible in the above example.

Comment: Okay now it solved the problem, now why? the color in login-section class is not specified as the text inside the textbox.

Comment: It's because of the parent element (login-section) takes precedent and it's color is white.